# Encountered memory leak when using numpy.mean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-leaks

When I am trying to calculate the mean of a large dimensional array using numpy I use something like:

```
loading_mean = np.mean(results[1][:,:,0,:,:], axis = 1)
```

where results[1] is a five dimensional numpy array, with shape equals to (2019, 5000, 2, 62, 5). 
From activity monitor I noticed that the memory goes up to 48.13GB. 
Then I wrote a for loop to calculate this mean "one by one", like:

```
import gc 
for i in xrange(results[1].shape[0]): 
    one_loading_mean = np.mean(results[1][i,:,0,:,:], axis = 0)
    gc.collect()
```

However, the memory is still aggregated up to 48GB even although one_loading_mean has been overwritten at each iteration. Does anyone encounter this issue before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No the array itself is huge. (2019 × 5000 × 2 × 62 × 5) × 8 bytes = 46.6 GiB.

Comment: I noticed that, I was wrong in the description. But how do I calculate the array's mean in this case without blowing up my memory?

Comment: Does that array contains a lot of zeroes? If so, try to load it as a sparse array.

Comment: It's actually a dense a array, and forgive my lack of knowledge in the memory management. What are the reasons if I use view instead copy, my memory would be OK. For example loading = results[1][:,:,0,:,:], my memory would be like 1 GB, and loading = numpy.copy(results[1][:,:,0,:,:]), my memory will be blowed up.